# displaying bibliographic info in header

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

In my dissertation I have a section named "Case Study: *Spore* (Wright, 2008)".

My problem issue is that on the section header --- i'm using the document class Book --- it shows "Case Study: *Spore* (?).

From what I can deduce the header is processed before the bibliography so the bibliographic information is not replaced in the header.

Because I'm getting peripheral search results regarding header format and reference/bibliography replacement, at this point I'm just looking to override manually the section header text, for the whole section. Can this be done?

EDIT: Added a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}  
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\section{Case Study: \emph{Spore} \citep{Spore:ba}}

\citet{Spore:ba} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\begin{quotation}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum \citep{Spore:ba}.
\end{quotation}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Wright(2008)]{Spore:ba} Wright, Will (Designer) (2008). \emph{Spore} (1.0) [Windows] Redwood City, CA: Maxis / Electronic Arts

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should make no difference where you place the bibliography. Are your other references resolved without problem? Could you provide some code (preferably in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)) that replicates the problem?

Comment: Package `textcase` might solve your problem as it takes care of stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Werner thought, the bibliography key was the issue.

Your file complied with an error message, which indicated that `SPORE:BA` was being sought, and not found by `bibtex`. If you change every occurrence of `Spore:ba` to `SPORE:BA` it works.

If it's not critical to have the citation in the header, then you can use a short title to form the header, leaving the citation in the actual heading:

\section[Case Study: Spore]{Case Study: \emph{Spore} \citep{Spore:ba}}

Comment: Yes, I have seen that error message too. But why LaTeX is asking for an uppercase key when there is no trace of it in text or bibliography?

Comment: I think I got it. When the text goes into the header the \MakeUppercase also uppercases the key, thus, the key is  not found.

Comment: Great---problem solved, just use uppercase keys for those entries